# Raspbain on BBBW

Tags: raspbian

I am currently taking an Embedded systems course and the course required buying a BeagleBone Black Wireless single board computer. After I am done with my course I am wanting to work with Raspbian. Is it possible to run the Raspbian OS on a BeagleBone since they are both linux platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. They don't have the same type of chip and would require different kernels and GPU code. Since you can run Debian on a BBB and Raspbian is Debian based there is not much to be gained.

Comment: Ok, so it could be run on the BBBw from a virtual machine? I assume that would kill performance but is it possible that way?

Comment: Maybe, but again to what end? What would you gain? And none of the GPIO's etc will work.

Comment: Spend $10 and buy a PI zero W, you will be much happier.